# if object return empty, no div

Tags: angularjs

I only want to display the image div if the object returns an image, right now I'm outputting the image in my `<div class="image">`, however, if there's no image, then the `<div class="image">` should not output:

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="{{item.logo}}" alt="{{item.title}}" title="{{item.title}}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
<div class="image" ng-if="item">
  ...
</div>
```

See the [documentation for ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

You could also use `ng-show`, which will merely hide the div instead of removing it completely. See the [documentation for ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).